# Writing about systems of linear equations in German

Tags: mathematics

I'm a beginner German learner and a mathematician. I've been trying to write solutions to simple linear algebra questions in German in order to practice writing mathematics in German. I keep on having problems when I would usually use a word in English ending in "-ing".

Could someone help me translate the following two phrases:

> "By summing both sides of equations (1), (2) and (3) and dividing by
>   3, we get:"
>
> "Using equation (1), we get:"

Thanks for any help.
Conrad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- "Durch Addition beider Seiten der Gleichungen (1), (2) und (3) und Division durch 3, erhalten wir:"
- "Addition beider Seiten der Gleichungen (1), (2) und (3) und Division durch 3 ergibt"
- "Mit Hilfe von Gleichung (1) resultiert"
- "Verwendung von Gleichung (1) führt zu"

Comment: Instead of *resultiert*, you will often see *ergibt sich*, which is a little bit less formal.

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion:

> Aus der Addition beider Seiten der Gleichungen (1), (2) und (3) und
> Division durch 3, folgt:
>
> Aus (1) folgt:

Comment: Doesn't this signify a causal relationship rather than a simple solving?

Comment: @fzwo I think that applies to the synonyms given by akid too.

Answer (score 1):

> "By summing both sides of equations (1), (2) and (3) and dividing by 3, we get:"

Anderer Vorschlag, der ohne Substantivbildung auskommt:

> Wenn wir beide Seiten der Gleichungen (1), (2) und (3) summieren und anschließend durch 3 teilen, erhalten wir:

Addieren/summieren oder dividieren/teilen können gleichermaßen verwendet werden. Bernd_ks und akids Lösungen sind in meinen Augen gleichwertig - ich wollte lediglich zeigen, dass man es im Deutschen auch mit Verben ausdrücken kann.